# Windows 10 installation on VirtualBox is incredibly slow and buggy, fails with top spec hardware

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

PC Specs (In case it matters since my AMD 5000 series CPU does NOT have an iGPU)

- AMD 5800X kept at base clocks 4.1GHz all 8 cores (VBox registers this as 16 total cores)
- Nvidia RTX 3080 10GB
- 32 GB Ram
- Main OS is Windows 11 Pro fully registered
- ISO i am using is the free Win 10 ISO you get from the installation media (I need a Win 10 VM to do some pen testing)
- Assigned 120GB to the VDI for the ISO

My issues:

1. It takes over 5mins just to load up the initial installation screen
2. Cursor moves at 30Hz (Behavior is the same on both a 100Hz ultrawide or 60Hz 24in)
3. Actual installation took over 3 hours before failing

Below details the settings I used:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There's no reason my hardware would be the limiting factor here since I'm assigning far more than Vbox needs. I have tried many different iterations of settings with no luck.

[image]

Just my theory but I don't ever dabble with VMs so i got no clue here: My RTX 3080 has to serve both the main OS (win 11) and the VM (win 10). Is there some hardware lock disabling my 3080's ability to virtualize the win 10 VM by splitting its own resources?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using KVM paravirtualization? Hyper-V is the default for Windows VMs AFAIR.

Comment: I tried Hyper-V and the same slowness persists. I saw online one guy suggested KVM so I'm trying that right now. EDIT: Trying Hyper-V now but still stuck at the logo currently

Comment: Regarding your theory: yes, the VM isn't utilising any hardware acceleration until VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed, but that should only affect rendering performance and doesn't explain this extreme slowness. How did the installation fail exactly?

Comment: Just wondering, is the CPU virtualization option enabled in the Firmware Settings (BIOS/UEFI) of the host hardware motherboard?

Comment: @JohnDoeDeer - This has nothing to do with your RTX 3080.  In fact your VM cannot even use it as it's currently configured. Hardware virtualization (AMD-V) is a feature of the CPU not the GPU.

Comment: @patkim - If AMD-V was disabled the VM wouldn't even start. The screenshots clearly indicate the author has installed a 64-bit operating system on the virtual HDD.